# What Amazon Cloudwatch metrics I should choose for scalability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have application is deployed by Elastic Beanstalk. It only connecting to ElasticCache.

I am testing my script capacity using siege utility

**siege -c 500 -r 1000 -b myurl**

My summary:

> Transactions:            12671 hits
>
> Availability:            92.45 %
>
> Elapsed time:           414.56 secs
>
> Data transferred:        12.42 MB
>
> Response time:                8.87 secs
>
> Transaction rate:        30.56 trans/sec
>
> Throughput:               0.03 MB/sec
>
> Concurrency:            271.00
>
> Successful transactions:       12671
>
> Failed transactions:          1035
>
> Longest transaction:         92.94
>
> Shortest transaction:         0.35

So my application is not 100% available.

But I watching CloudWatch metrics and I don't see any warnings about it.

[image]

I need to scale my application. But what metrics I should choose?

Comment: use the --time flag for siege and have it run for at least 15 minutes. your graphs imply that you do not have detailed monitoring enabled. Also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring_ec2.html

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to determine which metric shows something weird.

We don't see the Cloudwatch latency metric in your screenshot but it exists. As seen in your test result, the latency of your requests is not good at all (8 seconds). So it is a good candidate for the scalability configuration.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate why? As it stands now, your post is too curt to be a valid answer.

Comment: The idea is to determine which metric shows something weird. Here, the latency metric is not good at all. So it is a good candidate for the scalability configuration.

Comment: please feel free to edit this consideration into your answer.